# Transfer stats from one player to another in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently uninstalled my minecraft and installed the game again, but for another launcher, what happened is that I lost my stats, broken blocks, dead mobs and such, I didn't change my nickname or anything, just uninstalled and installed the game on another launcher, does anyone know how I can take the statistics I used before and use them again?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Stats are now per-world.

You can find your related stat data in `/[Minecraft Directory]/saves/[Save Name]/stats/[guid].json`.

Just rename the file with your old account's GUID to the new account's GUID and you'll leave off as if you were the previous account.

---

If you did not backup your worlds... This unfortunately means you have lost your data. There is no way to get it back, like there is no way to go from a burnt piece of paper back into pristine condition.

Comment: The problem is that I continued playing even after this happened, I didn't know about this technique of just renaming the file. Is there any way I can at least edit the data in this new file that was generated for me to join the data from the old file and the new file?

Comment: @PedroAugusto Just open it like any other JSON file in Notepad and transfer the numbers over.